# Is the Microsoft Graph Beta endpoint metadata invalid due name clash?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The Microsoft Graph beta endpoint [metadata](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata?$format=xml) appears to be invalid against the OData 4 specification at the moment (20 June 2020).

In particular, the one EntityContainer has two members with the same name:

```
<EntitySet Name="settings" EntityType="microsoft.graph.directorySetting"/>
...
<Singleton Name="settings" Type="microsoft.graph.entitlementManagementSettings"/>
```

This appears to contravene the OData 4 [specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-csdl-xml/v4.01/odata-csdl-xml-v4.01.html#_Toc38530392) which says:

> Entity set, singleton, action import, and function import names MUST be unique within an entity container.

Is the beta endpoint metadata invalid and how do I get it fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting this issue, and sorry for the late response.
The Singleton will be removed (was incorrectly published) along with the other top level EntitySets for entitlementManagement. This update should be visible by the end of this week (17th July).